# QInputDialog center screen or center dialog

Tags: c++, qt

I have this code:

```
QString text = QInputDialog::getText(this, tr("Key:"), tr("Key:"), QLineEdit::Password, "", &ok);
```

I can't make this dialog appear center screen, I went through WindowFlags and I tried initializing `QInputDialog` as a variable, calling move and then calling `getText`, for sure it doesn't work either as window is not initialized yet to be moved. I don't want to create antoher thread/timer to move it after calling getText, it's not good idea.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will not work, because when you use `QInputDialog` as a variable, then you should not use `static` methods anymore. So you need something like next code which is equivalent to static method because call `exec()` (modal dialog by default). Works normal for me:

```
QString mText;
QInputDialog *inp = new QInputDialog(this);
inp->setLabelText(tr("Key:"));
inp->setWindowTitle(tr("Key:"));
inp->setTextEchoMode(QLineEdit::Password);
inp->adjustSize();
inp->move(QApplication::desktop()->screen()->rect().center() - inp->rect().center());
if(inp->exec() == QDialog::Accepted)
    mText = inp->textValue();
qDebug() << mText;
```

Also possible code to center dialog:

```
QSize screenSize = QApplication::desktop()->geometry().size();
int primaryScreenWidth = screenSize.width();
int primaryScreeHeight= screenSize.height();
int widgetWidth = inp->width();
int widgetHeight= inp->height();
inp->move(primaryScreenWidth/2 - widgetWidth/2, primaryScreeHeight/2 - widgetHeight/2);
```

Comment: Thank you once again! It did exactly what I wanted